# using jspdf n GWT

Tags: gwt, jspdf

I am trying to get a PDF in GWT from client side 
I am using jspdf for that

Here is my code in GWT client side onModuleLoad

```
    public void onModuleLoad() {

    Button btn = new Button("click");
    RootPanel.get().add(btn);
    btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            callJs();
        }});

}

public native void callJs() /*-{
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
    doc.save('Test.pdf');

}-*/;
```

}

In my project.html file,
I added these in my header

```
          <script type="text/javascript" src="examples/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.plugin.from_html.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FileSaver.js"></script>
```

I have downloaded the jspdf  and put inside my war folder

Now when i Click on the button I get the error in console:

```
                 jsPDF is not defined
```

Please suggest what I am missing ..

NOTE: If i use the same above code within my project.html page 
It works fine 
but it doesnt work when i put the same code inside my JSNI method

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>` has not been loaded by your browser (404 ?).

Be sure that the jspdf.js file is at the root of you .war (with your project.html)

Comment: not getting 404..I have all these at root of my war with project.html ...FileSaver.js
jquery-2.1.0.min.js
jspdf.js
jspdf.plugin.addimage.js
jspdf.plugin.autoprint.js
jspdf.plugin.cell.js
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
jspdf.plugin.javascript.js
jspdf.plugin.png_support.js
jspdf.plugin.sillysvgrenderer.js
jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js
jspdf.plugin.total_pages.js
and the libraries:

base64.js
sprintf.js

Comment: If i put this javascript code inside my project.html.. I get a different error .. ".saveAs not defined"

Comment: do we need to add some dependency or war , or anything else of what i already have

Comment: I've tested your js code and everything is ok. Your jspdf.js may be corrupted.

Comment: I changed var doc = new jsPDF();    to   var doc = $jsPDF();  and it started working...